# How can I solve this KeyError for "country" key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, keyerror

When I run the below code cell by cell then It works up to finding the special characters in the data frame. When I run the cell with code `df['country'] = df['country'].replace('?',np.nan)` (to replace the special character to `nan` and then drop the columns) then a `KeyError` is raised.

```
# Import libraries 

import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, 
import pandas.util.testing as tm

# Libraries for data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as pplt  
import seaborn as sns 
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

# Import scikit_learn module for the algorithm/model: Linear Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
# Import scikit_learn module to split the dataset into train.test sub-datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
# Import scikit_learn module for k-fold cross validation
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
# import the metrics class
from sklearn import metrics
# import stats for accuracy 
import statsmodels.api as sm

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from google.colab import files
upload=files.upload()

#load the dataset provided
salary_dataset = pd.read_csv('adult.csv')
salary_dataset.head()

# salary dataset info to find columns and count of the data 
salary_dataset.info()

#replacing some special character columns names with proper names 
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df.rename(columns={'capital-gain': 'capital gain', 'capital-loss': 'capital loss', 'native-country': 'country','hours-per-week': 'hours per week','marital-status': 'marital'}, inplace=True)
df.columns

#Finding the special characters in the data frame 
df.isin(['?']).sum(axis=0)

# code will replace the special character to nan and then drop the columns 
df['country'] = df['country'].replace('?',np.nan)
df['workclass'] = df['workclass'].replace('?',np.nan)
df['occupation'] = df['occupation'].replace('?',np.nan)
#dropping the NaN rows now 
df.dropna(how='any',inplace=True)
```

Comment: You define `df` as an empty dataframe (`df = pd.DataFrame([])`). It has no columns, so it throws a `KeyError` when you call one. Perhaps you mean to process `salary_dataset`?.

Comment: Thank you. It works. That was my silly mistake.